# Suprimir formato de fecha por defecto en MS Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

Estoy armando un archivo excel a partir de una tabla HTML, para ello estoy usando "excellentexport" de github.com/jmaister/excellentexport la exportación transcurre sin problemas, salvo las columnas que tengan formato de fecha.
el dato original llega (por ejemplo) con un valor "1998-12-04" pero cuando abro el excel exportado este muestra un valor 4/12/1998, pero necesito que conserve el dato con el formato previo.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<table id="datos">
 <tr>
  <td>Pedro Romero</td>
  <td>1988-12-04</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Y el código JS que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/excellentexport.min.js"></script>
<a download="Usuarios.xls" class="btn" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'usuarios', 'Lista_usuarios');">
Exportar a Excel
</a>
```

Entiendo que manualmente puedo cambiar el formato de fecha, pero necesito que sea algo automático porque el archivo excel exportado será consumido por otra aplicación de manera directa, por lo que no podrá ser alterado manualmente ... lo peor es que es una restricción, porque tiene que ser formato XLS y no CSV

Comment: ¿Por qué es imprescindible el cambio de formato? En Excel, las fechas son números. Tanto `1988-12-04` como `4/12/199` se refieren al mismo valor, y Excel puede trabajar con ello. ¿Quizás forzando que lo lea como texto?

Comment: El problema es que el archivo excel generado es consumido por una tercera aplicación de manera directa y por algún motivo si la fecha sale como 4/12/1988 da error, en cambio cuando sale como 1988-12-04 no da error, mi idea sería hacer que la librería que uso para convertir HTML a EXCEL (excellentexport) creara los campos de fecha explícitamente como campos de texto para que luego Excel no los altere y puedan ser consumidos con el formato requerido (1988-12-04) pero no se como hacer que "excellentexport" defina explícitamente un campo como "texto"

Comment: Prueba a añadir un apóstrofe antes de cada fecha. En vez de `1988-12-04`, prueba con `'1988-12-04`. Esto fuerza en Excel que se mantenga el formato,

Comment: Lo de añadir el apóstrofe ya lo había probado, pero reitero, el archivo excel se consume directo por otra aplicación, cuando añades un apóstrofe, y abres el excel desde MS EXCEL todo bien, pero cuando se consume por la otra aplicación igual genera un error porque excel mantiene dicho apóstrofe en el documento aunque no lo muestre, por ello al aplicación receptora no puede procesar la fecha correctamente ...